# Facet blocks are not appearing, when indexed view block is called programmatically with views_embed_view

Tags: blocks, search

I have made an indexed view of my products. In that view, i have a page and a block. If I output the block from drupal/admin/structure/block the block view is shown together with the facet blocks.

Due to some conditions, I prefer to output the indexed view block programmatically, via page.tpl.php, and views_embed_view(), the indexed view block is shown correctly but then the facets are not displayed. Here is my code:

```
//level 2 webshop/categorie/subcategorie
            elseif( count($url_array)==4 && $url_array[1]=="webshop"){
                // if ($url=="/webshop/auto"){
                $tax_arr=taxonomy_get_term_by_name($url_array[3],"product_categorie");
                $tax=reset($tax_arr);
                $tax_chi=taxonomy_get_children($tax->tid);
                $tax_chi_tids = "";
                $counter=0;
                foreach ($tax_chi as &$child) {
                    if ($counter == 0){
                        $chtid =$child->tid;
                    $tax_chi_tids .=$chtid ;
                    }
                    else{$tax_chi_tids = $tax_chi_tids."+".$child->tid;}
                    $counter ++;
                }
                //echo views_embed_view('product_categorieen', 'block_1',$tax->tid);
                echo views_embed_view('view_products_index_product_hh','block_1',$tax_chi_tids);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, i have fixed it, putting the facet blocks also in the page.tpl.php, for me in the first sidebar. I iterated all active facet blocks in the block table an d then displayed each one with this code:

```
        $block_facet = block_load($module, $delta);
        print render(_block_get_renderable_array( _block_render_blocks(array($block_facet))));
```